# How to create Rollup summary between standard and custom objects where the detail object displays the total amount of opportunities.

Tags: master-detail, roll-up-summary

I have two objects 'Opportunity' and 'Project'. I want to create a Roll-up summary where the sum of all opportunities raised to a particular project can be displayed in that Project object.
The problem I have is that newly created projects do not have opportunities at the start, so by creating a master detail relationship between these two objects where Opportunity is parent and Project is child would enforce a user to look-up and assign an opportunity when creating a new Project, if not assigned it would not allow the user to proceed with saving.  There is also a condition, the sum should be only aggregated if user selects opportunity 'Received' from the picklist  in Opportunity object. Is there any way i can achieve this without coding.

Hope it makes sense and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your problem statement is confusing  - which object is the parent - Project or Oppo ? and what field in which child object is being rolled up to which field in parent object?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve via coding only because the standard object(Opportunity) cannot be on the detail side of a relationship with a custom object.